# Update an EntityObject with an another EntityObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a little problem and I need your help with it. I'm using Entity Framework for database handling and I want to update a dataset in this database.

I have an EntityObject with all the changes and want to be able to update this Object with  existing Object.

I'm using the following code to update the data:

```
IQueryable<Competitors> getCompetitor = DatabaseObject.Competitors.Where(SelectOnly => SelectOnly.competitorID == competitorObject.competitorID);
Competitors competitor = getCompetitor.First();
competitor = competitorObject;
DatabaseObject.SaveChanges();
```

But this deosn't work. How can I update the date in database?

Comment: where does competitorObject come from?

Comment: The Object is a Parameter from the Method.

Comment: your object competitorObject is not in the Context. You need to update the properties of competitor from the properties of competitorObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that your `competitorObject` is of `Competitors` type (`competitor = competitorObject`), you have to attach it to your context, mark it as modified, and then save changes:

```
DatabaseObject.Competitors.Attach(competitorObject);
DatabaseObject.Entry(competitorObject).State = EntityState.Modified;
DatabaseObject.SaveChanges();
```

There's no need to retrieve source object in your case, but without attaching, the context knows nothing about your updated object.

The piece of code, which is marking an object as modified, can be a little different, if you're using `ObjectContext` API instead of `DbContext` API:

```
DatabaseObject.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(competitorObject).SetModified();
```

Comment: This doesn´t work, because System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntry.State
is ReadOnly.

Comment: @DennisHeldt: sorry, updated the answer. I had used `ObjectContext` API two years or more ago.

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need to make to your code to get it to work is update at least one property on the fetched entity.  You are updating the reference, not the property values so like this:

```
IQueryable<Competitors> getCompetitor = DatabaseObject.Competitors.Where(SelectOnly =>       SelectOnly.competitorID == competitorObject.competitorID);
Competitors competitor = getCompetitor.First();
competitor.Name = competitorObject.Name;
competitor.Contact = competitorObject.Contact;
DatabaseObject.SaveChanges();
```

Or as Dennis has said you can attach the `CompetitorObject` to the context and mark it as modified.  Doing it that way will override all the properties of the existing `Competitors` record with the values of `CompetitorObject`.

Comment: This is an inefficient way, because of extra query to database. If he has constructed object, he just needs to attach it.